# Django Search Product feature issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I was trying to create a search functionality in Django, I have some data stored in my Django database and I am searching product **name** and I am getting it:

```
Please make sure to enter relevant search query
```

*Please check my code and let me know where I am Mistaking.*

Here is my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="ShopHome"),
    path("about/", views.about, name="AboutUs"),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="ContactUs"),
    path("tracker/", views.tracker, name="TrackingStatus"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="Search"),
    path("products/<int:myid>", views.productView, name="ProductView"),
    path("checkout/", views.checkout, name="Checkout"),
]
```

here is my `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product, Contact, Orders, OrderUpdate
from math import ceil
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

def searchMatch(query, item):
    '''return true only if query matches the item'''
    if query in item.desc.lower() or query in item.product_name.lower() or query in item.category.lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False


def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search')
    allProds = []
    catprods = Product.objects.values('category', 'id')
    cats = {item['category'] for item in catprods}
    for cat in cats:
        prodtemp = Product.objects.filter(category=cat)
        prod = [item for item in prodtemp if searchMatch(query, item)]

        n = len(prod)
        nSlides = n // 4 + ceil((n / 4) - (n // 4))
        if len(prod) != 0:
            allProds.append([prod, range(1, nSlides), nSlides])
    params = {'allProds': allProds, "msg": ""}
    if len(allProds) == 0 or len(query) < 4:
        params = {'msg': "Please make sure to enter relevant search query"}
    return render(request, 'shop/search.html', params)
```

here is my `base.html` file: *(For the Navbar Search)*

```
<form method='get' action='/shop/search/' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" id="search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

here is my `models.py` file:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

here is my `search.html` file: *(From Template)*

```
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}
{% extends 'shop/basic.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<div class="container">
    <!--Slideshow starts here -->
    {% for product, range, nSlides in allProds %}
    <h5 class="my-4">Flash Sale On {{product.0.category}} - Recommended Items</h5>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="demo{{forloop.counter}}" class="col carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                {% for i in range %}
                <li data-target="#demo{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" data-slide-to="{{i}}"></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    {% for i in product %}
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card align-items-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" id="namepr{{i.id}}">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{i.desc|slice:"0:53"}}...</p>
                                <h6 class="card-title" >Price: <span id="pricepr{{i.id}}">{{i.price}}</span></h6>
                                <span id="divpr{{i.id}}" class="divpr">
                                    <button id="pr{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>
                                </span>
                                <a href="/shop/products/{{i.id}}"><button id="qv{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-primary cart">QuickView</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- left and right controls for the slide -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo{{forloop.counter}}" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
<script>
{% if msg|length != 0 %}
alert('{{msg}}');
window.location.href = "/"
{% endif %}
// Find out the cart items from localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem('cart') == null) {
    var cart = {};
} else {
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    updateCart(cart);
}
// If the add to cart button is clicked, add/increment the item
//$('.cart').click(function() {
    $('.divpr').on('click', 'button.cart', function(){
    var idstr = this.id.toString();
    if (cart[idstr] != undefined) {
        qty = cart[idstr][0] + 1;
    } else {
        qty = 1;
        name = document.getElementById('name'+idstr).innerHTML;
        price = document.getElementById('price'+idstr).innerHTML;
        cart[idstr] = [qty, name, parseInt(price)];
    }
    updateCart(cart);
});
//Add Popover to cart
$('#popcart').popover();
updatePopover(cart);
function updatePopover(cart) {
    console.log('We are inside updatePopover');
    var popStr = "";
    popStr = popStr + "<h5> Cart for your items in my shopping cart </h5><div class='mx-2 my-2'>";
    var i = 1;
    for (var item in cart) {
        popStr = popStr + "<b>" + i + "</b>. ";
        popStr = popStr + document.getElementById('name' + item).innerHTML.slice(0, 19) + "... Qty: " + cart[item][0] + '<br>';
        i = i + 1;
    }
    popStr = popStr + "</div> <a href='/shop/checkout'><button class='btn btn-primary' id ='checkout'>Checkout</button></a> <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='clearCart()' id ='clearCart'>Clear Cart</button>     "
    console.log(popStr);
    document.getElementById('popcart').setAttribute('data-content', popStr);
    $('#popcart').popover('show');
}
function clearCart() {
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    for (var item in cart) {
        document.getElementById('div' + item).innerHTML = '<button id="' + item + '" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add To Cart</button>'
    }
    localStorage.clear();
    cart = {};
    updateCart(cart);
}
function updateCart(cart) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var item in cart) {
        sum = sum + cart[item][0];
        document.getElementById('div' + item).innerHTML = "<button id='minus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary minus'>-</button> <span id='val" + item + "''>" + cart[item][0] + "</span> <button id='plus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary plus'> + </button>";
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = sum;
    console.log(cart);
    updatePopover(cart);
}
// If plus or minus button is clicked, change the cart as well as the display value
$('.divpr').on("click", "button.minus", function() {
    a = this.id.slice(7, );
    cart['pr' + a][0] = cart['pr' + a][0] - 1;
    cart['pr' + a][0] = Math.max(0, cart['pr' + a][0]);
    if (cart['pr' + a][0] == 0){
        document.getElementById('divpr' + a).innerHTML = '<button id="pr'+a+'" class="btn btn-primary cart">Add to Cart</button>';
        delete cart['pr'+a];
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('valpr' + a).innerHTML = cart['pr' + a][0];
    }
    updateCart(cart);
});
$('.divpr').on("click", "button.plus", function() {
    a = this.id.slice(6, );
    cart['pr' + a][0] = cart['pr' + a][0] + 1;
    document.getElementById('valpr' + a).innerHTML = cart['pr' + a][0];
    updateCart(cart);
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```